# Pass text from activity to another fragment

Tags: android, bundle

In my Listview i had set the OnItemClickListener to take the latitude and longitude of the location and i wan pass this to another fragment call AddEvent. Below is my code.

```
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    double lat = ((Address)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getLatitude();
                    double lon = ((Address)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getLongitude();
                    String loc = "lat: " + lat + "\n" + "lon: " + lon;


                    AddEvent addEvent = new AddEvent();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("location", loc);
                    addEvent.setArguments(b);

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container2, addEvent, "Location").commit();
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

Below is the code in AddEvent.java. i had set the getArguments.getString() like below code.

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container ,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_event, container, false);

    btnTimePicker = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btntime);
    btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDatePicker = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btndate);
    btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnLocation = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnlocation);
    btnLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

    locationtxt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.location_text);

    Bundle b = getArguments();
    if(b != null){
        locationtxt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.location_text);
        String location = getArguments().getString("location");
        locationtxt.setText(location);


    }


    return rootView;

}
```

Why i set cant pass the text into the Edittext box? no error show and run perfectly with no any force close. Jux when return back to AddEvent fragment. The location_text still blank.

Comment: remove `finish();` from `onItemClick`

Comment: have you check loc value onItemClick ?

Comment: why you initializing 'locationtxt' two times

Comment: I want to close current activity o..

Comment: got value... jux dun know why cant pass to another fragment